# How can I access a row through data-id attribute in asp.net webforms?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

How can I access a row through data-id attribute in asp.net webforms? I have an edit button in a column on my table and I need to access the User_ID in that row. I I've seen examples with MVC but not webforms.

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditMenu" id="btnEdit" data-id="<%=TableId.Rows["User_ID"] %>">
    Edit
</button>
```

Comment: You want to access `data-id` via jQuery or in C#?

Comment: Sorry, I need to access through jQuery. I want to click the edit button on my table and access the User_ID field in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via jQuery as follows:

```
$('#btnEdit').on('click', function(){
    var userId = $(this).data('id');
    //do something with userId 
});
```

Please note the above snippet will work only if you are using jQuery version 1.4.3 or greater. If it's not then use the below snippet:

```
$('#btnEdit').on('click', function(){
    var userId = $(this).attr("data-id")
    //do something with userId 
});
```